# Paint: How to put spaces between vertical lines onDraw

Tags: java, android, android-graphics, android-paint

I found this code here on SO, but I'm new to drawing things, this Visualizer Class draws ok, but I want to put spaces between the vertical lines, like how the waveform on Soundcloud looks.

```
public class VisualizerView extends View {
private static final int LINE_WIDTH = 6; // width of visualizer lines
private static final int LINE_SCALE = 7; // scales visualizer lines
private List<Float> amplitudes;
private int         width; // width of this View
private int         height; // height of this View
private Paint       linePaint;

// constructor
public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    linePaint = new Paint(); // create Paint for lines
    linePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    linePaint.setStrokeWidth(LINE_WIDTH);
}

// called when the dimensions of the View change
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldw, int oldh) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.amplitudes = new ArrayList<>(this.width / LINE_WIDTH);
}

public void clear() {
    amplitudes.clear();
}


public void addAmplitude(float amplitude) {

    // add newest to the amplitudes ArrayList
    amplitudes.add(amplitude);

    // if the power lines completely fill the VisualizerView
    if (amplitudes.size() * LINE_WIDTH >= width) {
        // remove oldest power value
        amplitudes.remove(0);
    }
}

// draw the visualizer with scaled lines representing the amplitudes
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // get the middle of the View
    int middle = height / 2;

    // start curX at zero
    float curX = 0;

    // for each item in the amplitudes ArrayList
    for (float power : amplitudes) {
        float scaledHeight = power / LINE_SCALE; // scale the power

        // increase X by LINE_WIDTH
        curX += LINE_WIDTH;

        // draw a line representing this item in the amplitudes ArrayList
        float startY = middle + scaledHeight / 2;
        float stopY  = middle - scaledHeight / 2;
        canvas.drawLine(curX, startY, curX, stopY, linePaint);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: after draw line add  curX = curX+10;  10 is just a padding value that you can define

Comment: @Raghunandan, ohhh thanks, that does it.